# Creating Pixel Art Maker Grid

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create a pixel art maker that the user can choose the grid size (or namely Canvas) to work on. However, my code isn't work - specifically there are table rows being created, but not actually showing. I've linked both my JavaSctipt and HTML code to help.

Here's my code:

```js
let color = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
    let table = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas");
    let sizePicker = document.getElementById("sizePicker");
    
    let height = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
    let width = document.getElementById("inputWeight").value;
    makeGrid(height, width);
    
    sizePicker.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    
      e.preventDefault();
    
      let height = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
      let width = document.getElementById("inputWeight").value;
      table.firstElementChild.remove();
    
      makeGrid(height, width);
    
    });
    
    function makeGrid(height, width){
    
     for(let i=0; i<= height; i++){
      let row = table.insertRow(i);
      for(let j=0; j<= width; j++){
       let cell = row.insertCell(j);
       cell.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
       })
      }
     }
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Pixel Art Maker</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>
    
       <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>
    
       <h2>Choose Grid Size:</h2>
       <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
       </form>
    
       <h2>Pick A Color:</h2>
       <input type="color" id="colorPicker">
    
       <h2>Canvas</h2>
       <table id="pixelCanvas">
       </table>
    
      <script src="main.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It would be useful to have also the HTML code. You could try to create a working snippet.

Comment: Just edited in the HTML

Comment: I'd say it almost perfectly works. The table is created, cells are filled. The probably issue with cellspacing, so it is hard to target 1px with a click.
Meanwhile, you probably should try to use `mousemove` and fill with color after `mousedown` was triggered, because click won't work like this, you'll need to click each 1px cell to fill it with color.

Comment: Nothing is appearing on the canvas though. I see the table rows being created, but the canvas shows blank.

Comment: They are created, but they have no content, no borders, no background color... so you see nothing. Try to add a little bit of CSS like: `tr {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

td {
  width: 50px;
}`

Comment: So you filling them with a color on `click`, so they are empty initially.

Comment: To remove gaps you need to add `cellspacing=0` to `table` tag for sure.

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Comment: @extempl - Will you make the answer out of this talk?

Comment: I am still not sure what was the problem, and what is fixed the problem. cellspacing removing gaps, but it doesn't looks like this is was the initial issue, your code is fully working.

Comment: What's weird now, is the grid already starts at a 2x2.

Comment: that's because of `i <= height` and `j <= width`. Should be strictly `<`.

Comment: Or you start on 1 instead of 0. But what *extempl* advise you is more the standard convention. And, @extempl, I think the main issue was that the OP expected a table being drawn, but with the default style nothing gets shown on the screen. The `cellspacing` to remove the gaps is kinda optional, I actually like it with them :)

Comment: Got it! I appreciate the help a ton!

Comment: Any idea why the grid itself isn't adjusting to center when I do text-align: center to tr/td?

Comment: Do you mean aligning the table horizontally? I added `table { margin: auto }` to the answer. `text-align: center` does not work for `blocks`

Comment: Yes! That's it. I'm still learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the code is working, the table is created, but you see nothing because there is no initial styling for cells. I've added basic styles to simulate checkmate.
Also, there was two issues - gaps between cells (fixed with `cellspacing="0"`) and `n+1` rows/cells fixed with strict `<` condition in both loops.
Result is below:

```js
let color = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
let table = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas");
let sizePicker = document.getElementById("sizePicker");

let height = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
let width = document.getElementById("inputWeight").value;
makeGrid(height, width);

sizePicker.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();

  let height = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
  let width = document.getElementById("inputWeight").value;
  table.firstElementChild.remove();

  makeGrid(height, width);

});

function makeGrid(height, width) {

  for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    let row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      let cell = row.insertCell(j);
      cell.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
      })
    }
  }

}
```

```css
table {
  margin: auto
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Pixel Art Maker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

  <h2>Choose Grid Size:</h2>
  <form id="sizePicker">
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <h2>Pick A Color:</h2>
  <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

  <h2>Canvas</h2>
  <table id="pixelCanvas" cellspacing="0">
  </table>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, you should try to fill cells on `mousemove` event, after `mousedown` was triggered and until `mouseup`, or, at least, make cells bigger, as clicking `1px` cells is not really easy.

Meanwhile, it is good for training, but in further I'd recommend to go with `canvas`, as huge tables are not really good at performance and memory efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let color = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
let table = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas");
let sizePicker = document.getElementById("sizePicker");

let height = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
let width = document.getElementById("inputWeight").value;
makeGrid(height, width);

sizePicker.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();

  let height = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
  let width = document.getElementById("inputWeight").value;
  table.firstElementChild.remove();

  makeGrid(height, width);

});

function makeGrid(height, width) {

  for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    let row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      let cell = row.insertCell(j);
      cell.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
      })
    }
  }

}
```

```css
table {
  margin: auto
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Pixel Art Maker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Pixel Art Maker</h1>

  <h2>Choose Grid Size:</h2>
  <form id="sizePicker">
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <h2>Pick A Color:</h2>
  <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

  <h2>Canvas</h2>
  <table id="pixelCanvas" cellspacing="0">
  </table>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why I am alive?